# Java Regex to validate and capture ID and full name

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on a program that will run through a list of +20,000 records of ID, last name, first name, middle name. Now, I have a working regex that pulled the records with an ID sequence and grouped them as well as pulled records with a infraction number sequence and grouped them. The difference between the two is that the latter has a 12 character sequence (3 chars and 9 digits as opposed to a 9 digit ID sequence). 
There is the obvious problem of validating the names, some have last names that are 3+ i.e. de la Cruz, Smith-Doe, or just really long names. The same problem appears for middle names, which are sometimes just middle initial followed by a dot, simply the middle initial (no period), or the actual middle name.

I've created two classes to model the person objects, each with 4 fields (ID/tick num, lName, fName, mName). I want the regex to accurately group and store the 3 parts of a person's full name (as one person object which will be stored in a Vector) so I can later run a search against a person who is both the ticket list and ID list, to then store the matches in a separate list.

My problem is with how to accurately capture valid names. Here's a look at the regex I used to pull the two groups (this was done in python but I'm assuming I can reuse the regex:

```
'^([A-Z]{3}\d+)\s+([^\s]+([\D+])+)'  --> Ticket group
'^(\d+)\s+([^\s]+([\D+])+)'  ---> ID group
```

and here's a look at my ReadFile Class, which is meant to open and read the contents of the source file, storing the records as objects in people:

```
public class ReadFile {
    private Scanner myScan;

    public void openFile(){
        try{
            // Scanner object will hold source list
            myScan = new Scanner(new File("C:\\source.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Could not find file.");
        }
    }

    // readFile method will iterate through and store the contents of source list into people
    public void readFile() {
        Vector<People> people = new Vector<People>();
        while(myScan.hasNext()){
            People person = new People();
            person.setSbID(myScan.next());
            person.setLastName(myScan.next());
            person.setFirstName(myScan.next());
            person.setmInit(myScan.next());
            //add the person to the people list
            people.add(person);

            System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s \n", person.getID(), person.getLastName(), person.getFirstName(), person.getmInit());
        }
    }

    public void closeFile(){
        myScan.close();
    }
}
```

Right now the data is being passed to the person fields as elements being read from the scanner object but it's not doing it in smart way (.next()). The regex I used was in a python script that parsed the data correctly, I'm just unsure how to go about implementing it in Java. Current excerpt from Scanner:

```
people.add(person);
String text = person.toString();
String pattern = "^(\\d+)\\s+([^\\s]+([\\D+]+)";
boolean matches = Pattern.matches(pattern, text);
if (true) { System.out.println("matches = " + person); }
```

Sample data that the program should handle:

> 092331234 Smith, John M.
>   ABC097853827 Doe, Mark J

Comment: You've shown us code that manipulates the source file and resulting People object, but left out code that's actually parsing the source data via regex. Please post the code you've tried, along with some sample data.

Comment: Well, that's part of why I posted the question. Right now the data is being passed to the person fields as elements being read from the scanner object but it's not doing it in smart way (.next()). The regex I used was in a python script that parsed the data correctly, I'm just unsure how to go about implementing it in Java. So far I've written the expresion as  String pattern = "^(\\d+)\\s+([^\\s]+([\\D+])+";  @BrianStephens

Comment: @BrianStephens   
    `people.add(person);
    String text = person.toString();
    String pattern =  "^(\\d+)\\s+([^\\s]+([\\D+]+)";
    boolean matches = Pattern.matches(pattern, text);
    if (true) { 
    System.out.println("matches = " + person);`

Comment: Sample Data:  092331234 Smith, John M.      ABC097853827 Doe, Mark J

Comment: People can have no or multiple middle names, two+ word first names (ie: Mary Jane) and all kinds of variations.  Assuming 3 parts is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex that will match your sample data, splitting it into the four parts:

`^((?:[A-Z]{3})?\d{9})\s+(.+?),\s+(\S+)\s+(.+)$`

See it work on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uA8bD8/1).

I would be surprised if each line is as similar as you say. I agree with the comment by @adamdc78 that there's no way to determine what's part of a multi-word first name versus middle name.

My regex also makes these assumptions:

- the ID and name are the entire line
- there's always a comma separating the last name from the other names
- there's always a middle name

Comment: You're correct, I believe I am approaching this problem with the wrong thinking. I don't know if concatenating the name (first, middle, and last) as a one string and comparing the records from both list based on the concatenated name? @Brian Stephens